# How to show confirm dialog before leave screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dialog

I want to show alert dialog before dispose or leave the screen or at the latest show warning SnackBar, How can I do that?

I know how to show dialog and SnackBar but I don't know where I do that or when I tried to do it in dispose of life hook but it makes an error. due to context is dispose of before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `WillPopScope` widget:

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final value = await showDialog<bool>(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              content: Text('Are you sure you want to exit?'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('No'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Yes, exit'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        );

        return value == true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container()
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```